# Why does changing `__repr__` in a pandas DataFrame not change its display?

Tags: python, repr

Purely pedagogical, not trying to change anything. We have

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "abc"

a = A()
a
> abc
```

and

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
B.__repr__ = lambda x: "hi"
b = B()
b
> hi
```

But the following doesn't do anything.

```
pd.DataFrame.__repr__ = lambda x: "hi"
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]})
df
>   a   b
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

EDIT: this works in a Python REPL, the above was tested in a Jupyter notebook. The next question would be why it doesn't work in Jupyter, but that's a different question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get `hi` from the dataframe. Python 3.8.5, Pandas version 1.0.5

Comment: @khelwood Reproduced with an older version (0.24.2). It worked if overriding `__str__`.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 either upgrade pandas or override `__str__` instead of `__repr__`

Comment: Whoops, was testing this in a Jupyter notebook. In the python REPL, `__repr__` works.

Answer (score 0):

See if overriding string gives you the result that you want:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "abc"

    def __str__(self):
        return "abc"
```

If neither of those don't work then you aren't modifying the class that you think you are.